# Database storage vs File storage

Tags: java, mysql, database, performance, serialization

I have to make an invoice system where the invoices have to be stored for 10 years. What will be the best approach to store the invoices?

**1. An SQL database:**

```
Ex:
```

- Table Client (Code, Name, Address, Tel...)

  -Table Product (Part_Number, Description, Price...)

  -Table Invoice (Invoice_No, Client_code, Product, Quantity...)

The Invoice products will be tracked by the unique invoice number.:

```
Invoice_No | Client_Code | Product | Quantity

000000001 | Bob_025445 | Shoes...| 7

000000001 | Bob_025445 | Shirt......| 17

000000002 | Susan_22111| Hat.......| 1

000000001 | Bob_025445 | Boots ...| 1
```

**2. Save Invoice to file:** Serialize class to file:

```
    public class Invoice implements Serializable {
    private String invoiceNr;
    private Date invoiceDate; 
    private Client client;
    private List<products> products;

    ...
    }
```

Serialize as 00000001.inv, 00000002.inv... and deserialize for further consulting, print, etc... 
Saving to file I can generate an XML, but I will have the same problems as in serialization case.
First model is easier for generating reports for each detail, and fast, but, in 10 years, with only 10 invoices/day and only 10 items each invoice, the Invoice table will be pretty big ...

Second model seems better, but, if I want to generate a report about "Who bought shoes" for example, the program will have to iterate each file, witch is very slow.

So, please help me with any suggestion or third idea. Witch is the best practice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best advice is to choose a database engine whenever you have complex data to represent with much of information.

There are many reasons, most database engines are designed to be scalable and the performance and reliability you get from them is in most times much much better than to write one in your hands, plus they abstract away many complexities, yes handling files is hard and you won't know it until you try it, it's so much easier with SQL .

Note that some database engines are actually file-based(like sqlite) in that it stores everything in a file and doesn't need server.

Whether to choose a database server(like mysql) or a file-based like sqlite depends on your application, file-based is suited for desktop-applications data and mysql is suited for web-applications(or any application that is network-based).

All these and more, you can do some things to make the database performance better(like indexes) and the techniques that those give you is so hard to implement by hand too.

In your case I suggest you use a database engine, though I can't say whether sqlite or mysql or others as it depends on your needs.

One advice left, it is considered bad practice to define primary-keys as strings(Invoice_No should be an integer), you can control its format and max size so you don't need a String.

The only thing I would worry about when using a SQL-database is the programming language I'll use to connect to it, I don't have experience with java here but in C# it's just easy with LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the case for big data... it is suitable for big storage and fast for generating reports. 
Just make sure that you don't need to update those data when ready to storing them.

there is Big insights for IBM implementation of the Big Data concepts but there is also other big data insights from Google and MS ....

Comment: Unless we are talking about millions of invoices per day (and even then), big data technology does not seem like the right choice here. Invoice data is rather small, well-structured and does not arrive at immense velocity. So none of Gartner's original "3V of big data" (volume, velocity, variety) indicate that it is a good candicate for big data technolgy. Traditional relational databases and data warehouses will probably work pretty well for the invoice data, as they have for the last couple of decades.

Comment: yeah u r right .. just it came to my mind u do have a large business having lots of invoices per month maybe

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you having two tables in old fashioned relational database mentality. Invoce and InvoiceHstr (Partitioned with Invoice Date).

Plus you may have a "Header" table for a summary report.

InvoiceHeader (Holds product, numberOFSold ..., fromDate, toDate ) etc.

Second just store last month files in this for example data of Invoice table, in your physical files.

For detailed search and further reporting, use union of two tables.

Furthermore if this invoices belong to a telecom operator or to a bank, then you gotta use BigData techniques. Also you may use some BI caching queries also .